# Map value from list of tuples to another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I would like to replace the values in list (foo) using a value from a list of tuples. The first value in each tuple is the field to map to the values in the first list. The second value in each tuple, in the list bar, is the value I want to replace in the list foo.

```
foo = ['a','b','c']
bar = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
```

Expected results:

```
result = ['1','2','3']
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
map(dict(bar).get, foo)
```

Comment: *though you may want to do `d = dict(bar)` `map(d.get, foo)` instead of `map(dict(bar…` so you don't create a dict each time you call the function. May do a real improvement if you're running it inside a big loop.* NOT

Comment: @zmo It doesn't create a new `dict` each time

Comment: `dict(bar).get` evaluates to a bound method, so the dictionary is created only once.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is it possible to change the default value 'none' for an unfound key?

Comment: @JBradley This solution loses it's elegance if you want to do that. You could use a `lambda` eg. `map(lambda k: dict(bar).get(k, VAL), foo)` in the `map`

Comment: @jamylak Or using [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). `map(partial(dict(bar).get, default=...), foo)`.

Comment: @Lattyware I thought so too but `dict.get` doesn't support kwargs

Comment: @jamylak Ugh, that's weird. I wonder why that call got made. Disregard that then.

Comment: If you want a different default than `None`, try this: `map(defaultdict(lambda: 'nothing', bar).__getitem__, foo)`

Answer (score 1):

Very short version:

```
[ dict(bar)[i] for i in foo ]
```

Consider doing the `dict(bar)` just once in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative which uses `itemgetter`:

```
>>> foo = ['a','b','c']
>>> bar = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(*foo)(dict(bar))
('1', '2', '3')
```

This gives a `tuple`, but that's easy enough to convert if actually necessary.  Note that this turns out to be a very efficient way to do this if the tuple is acceptible and you're re-using the same getter each time:

```
>>> def mgilson():
...     return itemgetter(*foo)(dict(bar))
... 
>>> def zwinck():
...     return map(dict(bar).get,foo)
... 
>>> def alfe():
...     b = dict(bar)
...     return [b[i] for i in foo]
... 
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('mgilson()','from __main__ import mgilson')
1.306307077407837
>>> timeit.timeit('zwinck()','from __main__ import zwinck')
1.6275198459625244
>>> timeit.timeit('alfe()','from __main__ import alfe')
1.2801191806793213
>>> def mgilson_mod(getter=itemgetter(*foo)):
...      return getter(dict(bar))
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('mgilson_mod()','from __main__ import mgilson_mod')
1.1312751770019531
```

<sub>Tests done on Ubuntu Linux with python2.7.3 64-bit</sub>

Comment: Interesting results, would like to see on `foo*1000` or something large. Also that's an unfair mod IMO considering you shouldn't know `foo` in advance.

Comment: @jamylak -- I don't know if OP does or doesn't know it in advance.  But there are times when you might know the keys you want in advance and as far as I can see it, mine is the only method which can actually take good advantage of that.  But, doing things with items which aren't found becomes a bit more messy -- (I'd need a `defaultdict(lambda:default)`)

Comment: Why does everyone misspell my name?

Comment: @JohnZwinck -- my most sincere apologies.  I have corrected it above (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that some items in `foo` may **not** need to be replaced

eg.

```
>>> foo = ['a','b','c', 'd']
>>> bar = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
>>> d = dict(bar)
>>> [d.get(x, x) for x in foo]
['1', '2', '3', 'd']
```